# Why flex container is smaller than its content

Tags: html, css

I have two containers, one that wraps two h2 tags, and another that wraps the h2 tags and a label above them. However, for some reason, both containers are smaller than the content within them. I'd like these containers to be the same width and height.

I've tried setting height and width of the containers to 100%.

```css
.label {
  padding: 3px 8px;
  background-color: #fbfb2f;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 20px; 
}

.label:after {
  content: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1774776/Yellow_Tag_Tail.svg");
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 37%; 
  margin-bottom: -19px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 72px;
  line-height: 0.1;
  max-width: 182px;
  margin-top: 42px;
}

.u-padding-left {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.u-center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="u-center">
  <div class="text-container">
    <div class="label">Take Your Pick!</div>
    <div class="heading-container">
      <h2>Subscribe,</h2>
      <h2 class="u-padding-left">Simplify</h2>
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```

I would like the text-container and heading-container to be the same width and height as their children.

Comment: Why you didn't write `text-container` and `heading-container` class from CSS?

Comment: Demo fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/6Lcsu4fb/

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the maximum width property from the h2. Then the container will be the same size of the content contained within it.

Comment: Nicely done. https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/6Lcsu4fb/4/ However, that rule must've had a purpose. What's the alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Its because of your line-height property on h2. remove the line-height property and max-width, and make width and height 100%. You will see it increase in height and size but that how it will look if your container contain full height of the text

```css
.label {
  padding: 3px 8px;
  background-color: #fbfb2f;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 20px; 
}

.label:after {
  content: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1774776/Yellow_Tag_Tail.svg");
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 37%; 
  margin-bottom: -19px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 72px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 42px;
}

.u-padding-left {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.u-center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="u-center">
  <div class="text-container">
    <div class="label">Take Your Pick!</div>
    <div class="heading-container">
      <h2>Subscribe,</h2>
      <h2 class="u-padding-left">Simplify</h2>
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div>
```